# DRY Code: Sass Bourbon why use some mixins?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Not sure if this question belongs on this board or not but I was wondering the benefit, if any, of using some of the mixins in Bourbon. The whole point of Sass is to write DRY code so why use:

```
.div{
 @import margin(10 10 10 10);
}
```

when you can just use normal css like

```
.div{
 margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bourbon's margin mixin takes four measurements and maps them to there respective **single-directional** property. I've never been a fan of single-directional margin properties, but according to [CSSWizardry](http://csswizardry.com/2012/06/single-direction-margin-declarations/) they have the following benefits:

> The benefits are, as I see them:
>
> - Easier to define vertical rhythm in one fell swoop.
> - More confidence in (re)moving components if you know their margins all push in the same direction.
> - Components and elements don’t have to necessarily live in a certain order if their margins aren’t dependent on adjoining sides.
> - Not being concerned with collapsing margins means one less thing to worry about.

The example you've given would actually compile out to the following CSS:

**SCSS**

```
.div {
    @import margin(10px 10px 10px 10px);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.div {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

See [Bourbon Docs](http://bourbon.io/docs/#directional-property) for more information on the directional property mixin.